# Custom input control (Awesomplete) won't submit 'value' attribute

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Trying to use a custom html input control (listbox substitute) called Awesomplete but it's not adding its 'value' attribute to querystring when the form is submitted using method=get.

```
<input class="awesomplete" data-minchars="1" name="finder" id="finder"
 style="width:180px; height:18px;" value="<% = Session("finder") %>"
```

If I remove the class and add `'type="text"'` it works fine. I'm thinking maybe it doesn't have a 'name' attribute. It does fire events when the value is changed and I could intercept these, but I don't want to mess with hidden inputs etc if I can help it. Can't believe I'm the only one that has struggled with this...

Comment: can you show a bit more of the code? The form + submit element/ Javascript would be very helpful.

Comment: Why not keep the class and add the type="text" attribute? Does that work?

Comment: Is there actually a value in the `Session("finder")` session variable?  Also, your `input` tag isn't closed properly; did you use `/>` or `></input>` or have you missed the closing angle bracket altogether?

Comment: By removing the class, you are probably disabling Awesomplete. Does the Awesomplete function work?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions! The problem was actually due to the fact that my form tags were unknowingly straddling an open div element. Everything apart from the Awesomplete input ignored my bug and worked properly. Awesomplete is indeed an awesome replacement for datalist when it's working!